# Most efficient way to get a hashable object for an arbitrary set of keys (of arbitrary data type)

Tags: c#, .net, performance, dictionary, hash

I have writing a method which needs to be able to take an arbitrary number of fields of data, combine them in some way into a hashable object, then hash this object in a dictionary for later lookup.

So far the best algorithm I've come up with is to take ToHashCode() for each field, then join the resulting hashcodes into a string using some kind of separator character (such as "|"), and then use this resulting string as a unique key for the dictionary.

Does anyone know of a more efficient way to do this? I was thinking perhaps there is some way to take the hashcode of each field, and do some mathematical operation to combine them into a unique hashable number, but this was just a guess.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:
I think people may be confused as to what exactly I mean. Tuples will not work in this situation because I need an *arbitrary* number of fields to be combined into a single hashable object. The number of fields is only known at runtime, not at design time.

The other solution given about combining all the hashcodes mathematically into a new hashcode also will not work, because I need an *object* that can be used as a key into a Dictionary. Using a hashcode as a key into a Dictionary is very dangerous I believe.

EDIT 2:
After thinking about this some more I think my original solution is not a good one. In the limiting case where there is a single field, my solution has degenerated into putting a string version of the hashcode into a Dictionary.

I think perhaps a better solution is to make a new type which takes an enumerable in its constructor, and implements GetHashCode(). The GetHashCode() function would then loop through each value of the enumerable and perform the usual type of accumulator logic in hash code functions. This way, the object can be stuck into a dictionary, hashset, etc. and behave as you would expect.

Comment: Whatever you choose, you run the risk of a collision. For your string version it might be negligible.

Comment: Yes, you can never avoid collisions completely, because a hashcode only has a limited number of distinct possible values.

Comment: I'd vote to use the mathematical combining of `GetHashCode()` and using that as a key, and have it be able to handle the collisions well.  For example `Dictionary<int, List<object>>` and if the list contains more than 1 object compare them to find the correct one.

Comment: @MgSam Please either accept an answer or provide additional information/clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here was realizing that any arbitrarily sized collection of objects can be hashed by simply treating it as an IEnumerable whose hashcode depends on the contents of the enumeration.

To do this I simply made a ValueAwareEnumerable class that implements IEnumerable. This class takes an enumerable in its only constructor. It then overrides GetHashCode() and Equals() so that they depend on the contents of the enumerable. The GetHashCode method is simply:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {
        int hash = 983;
        foreach (var item in _wrappedEnumerable)
           if(item != null)
              hash = hash * 457 + item.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

and Equals:

```
 public override bool Equals(object obj)
 {
     if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
     if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
     if (obj.GetType() != typeof (ValueAwareEnumerable<T>)) return false;
     return Equals((ValueAwareEnumerable<T>) obj);
 }

 public bool Equals(ValueAwareEnumerable<T> other)
 {
     if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
     if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;

     return _wrappedEnumerable.SequenceEqual(other);                               
 }
```

The caveat here is that it depends on the *order* of the enumerable. If needed, it's possible to make it order-independent by simply making GetHashCode() and Equals() sort the enumerable before iterating through it.

To finish it off, just add in an extension method somewhere for good measure:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ToValueAwareEnumerable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
   return new ValueAwareEnumerable<T>(enumerable);
}
```

And you can do things like:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<IEnumerable<int>>();
var veryImportantNumbers = new[] { 5, 8, 13, 20, 3, 100, 55, -5, 0 };
dictionary[veryImportantNumbers.ToValueAwareEnumerable()] = "Pastrami";
```

This will work for any data type, and even mixed data types, if you treat them as an `IEnumerable<Object>`.

Comment: +1, dont forget to check for nulls in hash function, it should never throw exceptions. Something like `hash = hash * 457 + (item == null ? 0 : item.GetHashCode());`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use a Tuple<> to combine the hashcodes of your fields.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, string>, MyClass>();
dict[Tuple.Create(myObj.Num, myObj.Str)] = myObj;
```

You could also combine the hashes yourself, but you risk getting it wrong.

Comment: And it chains Equality too. It might be the only option.

Comment: It is the most easy to maintain, and the builtin Tuples are quite fast too.

Answer (score 0):

> I was thinking perhaps there is some way to take the hashcode of each field, and do some mathematical operation to combine them into a unique hashable number, but this was just a guess.

Yes, that's exactly what you should do. Here's a common implementation:

```
unchecked
{
    int hash = 983;
    hash = hash * 457 + x.GetHashCode();
    hash = hash * 457 + y.GetHashCode();
    hash = hash * 457 + (z != null ? z.GetHashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}
```

Note that you're **not** supposed to use the hashcode as a dictionary key, since it won't be unique (collisions will typically be rare, but they're not impossible). If you want to use the object itself as the key, you must also override `Equals` so that if `x.Equals(y)`, then `x.GetHashCode() == y.GetHashCode()` (the reverse doesn't have to be true)

Comment: Combining hashes manually should run a bit faster than with Tuple<>, but it comes at a cost. Unless a careful profiling shows otherwise, I advise against combining hashes manually.

Comment: @EldritchConundrum, I guess it depends on what you want to do... I'm not sure I understood correctly what the OP is asking. Besides, Tuple<T> is not available in .NET 3.5 and earlier.

Comment: Yes, it's true. Before Tuples, you had to combine hashes manually. So, the best answer depends on both the .Net version and what the OP means by "efficient" :)

Comment: The problem with this is that it gives you a hashcode, not a hashable object. I need the resulting object to be able to go into a Dictionary.

Comment: @MgSam, perhaps a custom IEqualityComparer is what you need?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot safely use a standard has table in this case (unless you can provide additional restrictions).

Additional information is required to provide a good alternative, but I have one suggestion below.  Additional information might include:

- Use Case (how you are using the look up system, why you need the fields part of the key)
- Are the fields which can be combined defined at design time (note: this is not how many or which fields are being combined.  Instead it relates to where/when/how these fields are defined such that they can be combined).
- If the fields are defined at run time, how many total fields are there (number of all fields).
- What data is being stored for this strange key?
- How often will the data be written/read?

**Quick solution**:
Use nested hash tables.  For this solution you would need your fields to be sorted.  The first field is the key for the first table.  This would point to another hash table where the second field would be the key.  This would occur for each field until you the last field.  The last field would be the key for the data you are looking for.
To make this work you would need to define a custom object which has a property for data and a property for a hash table.

While this is an ok solution which uses existing .net data structures, it will not be very efficient.  For a more efficient solution please provide additional information.